ubuntu 24.04 open terminal from nautilus, active window don't switch to terminal
I've been using ubuntu 22.04 and I love it, recently I upgrade to ubuntu 24.04, there are a loooooot of issues I've been found. one of those is:
when I open terminal from nautilus via right click menu "open in terminal", the terminal opens fine, but the active window doesn't automatically switch to the terminal. So I have to click the newly opened terminal to focus on it to type in.
what do I do to make the newly created terminal window automatically active so I don't have to click on it again to type in.

I'm looking for this too, did you find anything?

@Marware 24.04 is just too buggy, so I've go back to 22.04 already
